# How to make a model.matrix in a specific way?

Tags: r, model.matrix

How would one produce a matrix that looks like this using model.matrix?

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    1    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    2    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    1    3    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    1    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    1    2    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    1    3    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    1    1
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    1    2
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    1    3
```

I produced the first matrix by

```
fit = lmer(Temp ~ 1 + (1 + Time|Id), data = Data) 
getME(fit, name = c("Z"))
```

Where

```
Time = rep(1:3, 3)
```

And Id

```
Id = c(0L, cumsum(diff(Time) < 0))
```

This is as close as I could get.

```
id = rep(c("a","b","c"),each = 3)
Z = model.matrix(~0+id)

  [,1] [,2] [,3]
1    1    0    0
2    1    0    0
3    1    0    0
4    0    1    0
5    0    1    0
6    0    1    0
7    0    0    1
8    0    0    1
9    0    0    1
```

Comment: Can you explain the elements of the first matrix? I mean, it is trivial to get you a matrix that looks like the first one, but I doubt it would be what you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not sure I get what you try to do, but does this work for you?

```
val = rep(1:3,3)
z = model.matrix(~0+id+id:val)
```